# using trig sub vs u-sub with $ \int_0^1 x^3 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \, dx $?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

I'm having a hard time understanding when I should use $u$-sub rather than trig sub. I have the problem
$$
\int_0^1 x^3 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \, dx
$$

My initial attempt was to use $x = \sin u$ as my trig sub but this was wrong. I didn't think to use $u$-sub as the $dx$ and $du$ wouldn't cancel out nicely. But the answer says to just use the $u$ equation and solve for $x$ then plug that into the $x^3$.

This brings me to my next question. If I have an square root integral and both $a$ and $x$ are $1$, do I need to use $u$-sub rather than trig sub?

Comment: Trig substitution is just a special type  of u-subsitution

Comment: $x=\sin u$ should work fine. What was your issue?

Comment: @DavidP, the other way around: $x = \sin u$ will work (trig substitutions are always "inverse" $u$ substitutions)

Comment: You can use whatever you want, as long as you do it right and it works. Sometimes there's one clear way to approach a problem, and sometimes the same problem (say, of evaluating an integral) can be successfully approached in multiple ways. That's the case here: we can evaluate this integral at least in two different ways — with a trig substitution or with a non-trig substitution.

Comment: You can avoid trig substitutions (at least, initially) when the power outside is odd. This is because $x^3=x^2\cdot x$ and $x\,dx=\frac12 dx^2$, so with $u=x^2$ you can reduce the powers under the integral in terms of $u$ and get $\frac12\int u\sqrt{1-u}\,du$. Now a second substitution $t=1-u$ reduces this to integrating a sum of powers. This will work with odd powers other than $3$, but not with even powers. The general rule of thumb is to see first if squares (or higher powers) can be eliminated by making $u$ a power of $x$. If not, you likely need trig.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good exercise because the answer is *do both!*

The "Pythagorean" expression (a square-root of a sum or difference of squares) suggests a trigonometric substitution. With $x = \sin t$, we have $\sqrt{1 - x^2} = \cos t$ (on the domain $0 \leq x \leq 1$ which corresponds to $0 \leq t \leq \pi/2$). Also, by differentiating, $dx = \cos t \, dt$. Putting this all together,
$$
\int_0^1 x^3 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \, dx 
= \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3 t \, \cos^2 t \, dt
$$

Now, the standard way to approach this integral is to recognize the odd power of $\sin t$, which suggests peeling off one copy to stick to the differential $dt$, converting the remaining integrand into a polynomial in $\cos t$. Try it yourself before revealing:

> $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^3 t \, \cos^2 t \, dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2 t \, \cos^2 t \, (\sin t \, dt) = \int_0^{\pi/2} (1 - \cos^2 t) \, \cos^2 t \, (\sin t \, dt). $$

Now, we make the substitution $u = \cos t$, which has differential $du = -\sin t \, dt$, so we are calculating

> $$ - \int_1^0 (1 - u^2) \, u^2 \, du = \int_0^1 (u^2 - u^4) \, du $$

Finally, we evaluate

> $$ \int_0^1 (u^2 - u^4) \, du = \bigl(\tfrac13 u^3 - \tfrac15 u^5 \bigr)\bigg|_0^1 = \tfrac13 - \tfrac15 = \tfrac{2}{15}. $$

---

If you just want the value of the definite integral, then you're done. But, this example can teach you something more subtle. Whenever you make two substitutions, you can go back and redo the calculation with a single substitution that does both at once. And when you do this, your integrand goes from algebraic to trigonometric and back to algebraic.
$$
u = \cos t = \cos (\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2} 
$$
This suggests that the substitution $u = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ would have worked from the start. Let's try: $u^2 = 1 - x^2$, so $2u \, du = - 2x \, dx$ for the differentials. Also, $x^2 = 1 - u^2$, and for the the limits, the $0$ and $1$ swap. Thus,

> $$ \int_0^1 x^3 \sqrt{1 - x^2} \, dx = \int_0^1 x^2 \sqrt{1 - x^2} (x \, dx) = \int_1^0 (1 - u^2) \, u \, (-u \, du) = \int_0^1 (u^2 - u^4) \, du $$

as before, but with no explicit reference to any trigonometric function.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $u=x^2$ transforms the integral into $$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 x^3 \sqrt{1-x^2} d x &=\int_0^1 x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2} \cdot x d x \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 u \sqrt{1-u} d u
\end{aligned}
$$
Decomposing the integrand into two yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1[1-(1-u)] \sqrt{1-u} d u \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-u} d u-\int_0^1(1-u)^{\frac{3}{2}} d u \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[-\frac{2}{3}(1-u)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{2}{5}(1-u)^{\frac{2}{2}}\right]_0^1\\&=\frac{2}{15} 
\end{aligned}
$$

---

For fun, we can do it by integration by parts.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=-\frac{1}{3} \int_0^1 x^2 d\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&=-\left[\frac{x^2\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{3}\right]_0^1+\frac{2}{3} \int_0^1 x\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} d x \\
&=-\frac{2}{3}\left[\frac{1}{5}\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}\right]_0^1=\frac{2}{15}
\end{aligned}
$$